# Entity not null validation message

Tags: java, spring-boot

Currently I have 2 entity's in my app like below. Both are not nullable.

```
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String name;

@Column(name = "ldap", nullable = false)
@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String ldap;
```

When I post with data, either name or ldap field with null, I like to have specific not null message to be display with field name.  Pls let me know, how to achieve this ?

for example,

```
{
 "name" : "check"
}
```

then, error message should be `ldap field should not be empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform few steps to achieve custom message:

```
  @Column
    @NotNull(message = "error.title.notnull")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30, message = "error.title.size")
    private String title;
    @Column
    @Size(max = 100, message = "error.description.size")
    private String description;
```

So, the next step is to make a MessageSource bean by adding one to SpringValidationApplication (the main class).

For example:

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
  ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageBundle = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
  messageBundle.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages");
  messageBundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
  return messageBundle;
}
```

This tells Spring to look at the messages folder for files starting with messages.

Next add a file called `messages.properties` inside src/main/resources/messages:

```
error.title.notnull=The title is a required field
error.title.size=The title should be between 1 and 30 characters
error.description.size=The description should be limited to 100 characters.
```

Detail can be found on this [link](https://g00glen00b.be/validating-the-input-of-your-rest-api-with-spring/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@NotNull` annotation:

```
@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
@NotNull(message = "ldap field should not be null"
@NotBlank(message = "ldap field should not be empty"
private String ldap;
```

I usually use `@NotEmpty` for trings instead of `@NotBlank` - it has message property too.