# Java Validator custom message still includes the field name

Tags: java, validation

I have the following annotation for a field:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "unique_name may not be empty")
@JsonProperty("unique_name")
private String uniqueName;
```

However, when I run a request, the error message I get back is:

> uniqueName unique_name may not be empty

Why is the message contains the field name `uniqueName`? How can I fix this so the message only says `unique_name may not be empty`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the plain message string in the annotation is actually using interpolation behind the scenes to prepend the field name. It looks like you probably want to use a custom `message.properties` file instead. See here: [Entity not null validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444955/entity-not-null-validation-message)

So in `src/main/resources/messages` you'd have a `messages.properties` file that contains the message, such as:

```
error.uniqueName.notEmpty=unique_name may not be empty
```

Then in your annotation:

```java
@NotEmpty(message = "error.uniqueName.notEmpty")
```